# Get dynamically created element that was click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to track what buttons users click via javascript/jquery. I have the following code

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-tracker]', function( event ) {

    var target = event.target;
    var targetName = $(target).data('tracker');

    console.log(targetName);
});
```

```html
<button data-tracker="test1">test1</button>
<i data-tracker="test2">test2</i>
<img data-tracker="test3">
```

At the moment this works as I want it to. When someone clicks on an element on the page that has the `data-tracker` attribute I log the value in the console.

I'm using datatables on some pages which dynamically creates elements from json returned from the server. I can't figure out how to record elements that have been dynamically created.

So all in all I want 1 function that will check if a user clicks on an element with the data-tracker attribute and output it's value to the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all** instead of something like this

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-tracker]', function( event ) {
    var target = event.target;
    var targetName = $(target).data('tracker');
    console.log(targetName);
});
```

You can do this

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-tracker]', function() {
    var targetName = $(this).data('tracker');
    console.log(targetName);
});
```

**Secondly**, the reason of this behavior may be because [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function works that way

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element. Returns the value that was set.

So when you dynamically add an element with attribute `data-tracker` there is no value set because it was not stored. So instead of using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) just use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-tracker]', function() {
    var targetName = $(this).attr('data-tracker');
    console.log(targetName);
});
```

Here is a snippet

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-tracker]', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-tracker'));
});

var num = 0;

$("#addElement").on('click', function() {
  $("<div>").attr('data-tracker', 'test value ' + num).html('Test value' + num).appendTo(".content");
  num++;
});
```

```css
[data-tracker] {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addElement">Add element</button>

<div class="content">
  <div data-tracker="value1">Value 1</div>
  <div data-tracker="value2">Value 2</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div data-tracker="value3">Value 3</div>
  <div data-tracker="value4">Value 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think, it would be better to use `var targetName = $(this).data('tracker') || $(this).attr('data-tracker');`

Comment: `$(this).data('tracker')` would surely work, no need to use `.attr()`

Comment: @Alexander It depeneds. If you change value of `data-tracker` in js, and then again check the value those two functions will return different output. `.data()` will return stored value (original) and `.attr()` will return changed value.

Comment: My idea is to set higher priority to `.data('tracker')` value, and if the value is `null` or `undefined`, then get value from `.attr('data-tracker')`. I don't enforce, this is your post ;)

Comment: @Alexander sure, I know how `||` works. The difference is minor actually, maybe indeed your idea is better :)

Comment: I've tried the above cod but it's not working. It's not registering a click event at all on dynamically created content but is working for static content

Comment: @Peck3277 In that case check in devtools if dynamically created elements have the `data-tracker` attribute.

Comment: Just checked and they do. I tried the following     $(document).on('click', 'a', function() { and it works. Just won't work if I try searching with the data-tracker attribute. Any thoughts?

Comment: That is very suspicouis. Perhaps there is a tiny typo in attribute name?

Comment: Ugh, there's no cure for stupidity. Your code works a dream, I was missing the closing " from my class so it was messing up the data attribute. Thanks so much for the help. Working like a dream now!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK to me. You are probably making some mistake when added elements with `JSON`, make sure you get that correct.

Here I've added a button to add elements to the page dynamically, you can verify

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-tracker]', function( event ) {

    var target = event.target;
    var targetName = $(target).data('tracker');

    console.log(targetName);
});

$("#new").click(function(){
   $("#d").append(`<button data-tracker="test1">test1</button>
<i data-tracker="test2">test2</i>
<img data-tracker="test3">`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d">
<button data-tracker="test1">test1</button>
<i data-tracker="test2">test2</i>
<img data-tracker="test3">
</div>
<br/>
<button id="new">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the `data-tracker` is a class name. And here is a example of how you adding a onclick event to all element with the same class name

```js
a = document.getElementsByClassName("data-tracker")

for (var key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key) && Number.isInteger(parseInt(key))) {
        a[key].addEventListener("click", function(){console.log('hi')});
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="data-tracker" value="button1"></input>
<input type="button" class=""  value="button2"></input>
<input type="button" class="data-tracker" value="button3"></input>
```